# i get cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>to string when execute the code below

Tags: c#

I need to search the file and move the file to another directory but i got the error cannot convert System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerableto string. Anyone can help?

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\EBMobileSyncService\Error", "*"+date+"?.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

if (file.Count() == 1)
{
    DialogResult retry = MessageBox.Show("Sales " + date + " Transfer Error", "Sales Transfer Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
    if (retry == DialogResult.Retry)
    {
        System.IO.File.Move(file, "@D:\\EB\\FTP\\EBPOSWMS\\Client\\ECOS\\Export");
        MessageBox.Show("Sales Moved");
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.IO.File.Move(` expects `string` value as first argument buy you are passing `IEnumerable<string>` to it. That's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

`file` is an array
so if there is only one file then you must pass in `file[0]` instead of `file`

```
System.IO.File.Move(file[0], "@D:\\EB\\FTP\\EBPOSWMS\\Client\\ECOS\\Export");
```

and change this

```
List<string> file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\EBMobileSyncService\Error", "*" + date + "?.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: i got the code is error with error message , "cannot apply indexing with [] to expression of type IEnumerable<string>" . actually i tried the code above before but still can't work.

Comment: I sitll getting error with code above , HAHA. and i found my own way to solve the problem with code 
'string strErrorFilePath = file.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                    File.Move(strErrorFilePath, Path.Combine(@"D:\EB\FTP\EBPOSWMS\Client\ECOS\Export\"+sub, Path.GetFileName(strErrorFilePath)) );'

Answer (score 0):

`File.Move` expect string paramter. But you are passing `IEnumerable` of string. so you need to pass only first string from list.

```
System.IO.File.Move expect string paramter.


    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\EBMobileSyncService\Error", "*"+date+"?.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        if (file.Count() == 1)
        {
            DialogResult retry = MessageBox.Show("Sales " + date + " Transfer Error", "Sales Transfer Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel);
            if (retry == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                System.IO.File.Move(file.First(), "@D:\\EB\\FTP\\EBPOSWMS\\Client\\ECOS\\Export");
                MessageBox.Show("Sales Moved");
            }
        }
```

Comment: i ran this code but when i click retry button there is a error occurred and saying "System.NotSupportedException" and  The given path's format is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I still getting error with code above , HAHA. and i found my own way to solve the problem with code `string strErrorFilePath = file.FirstOrDefault().ToString(); File.Move(strErrorFilePath, Path.Combine(@"D:\EB\FTP\EBPOSWMS\Client\ECOS\Export\"+sub, Path.GetFileName(strErrorFilePath)) );`